# Creating filenames with unicode characters

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8

I am looking for some guidelines for how to create filenames with Unicode characters. Consider:

```
use open qw( :std :utf8 );
use strict;
use utf8;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;
use Encode qw(encode);

my $utf8_file_name1 = encode('UTF-8', 'æ1', Encode::FB_CROAK | Encode::LEAVE_SRC);
my $utf8_file_name2 = 'æ2';
dd $utf8_file_name1;
dd $utf8_file_name2;
qx{touch $utf8_file_name1};
qx{touch $utf8_file_name2};
print (qx{ls æ*});
```

The output is:

```
"\xC3\xA61"
"\xE62"
æ1
æ2
```

Why doesn't it matter if I encode the filename in UTF8 or not? (The filename still becomes valid UTF8 either way.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of a bug called "The Unicode Bug". The equivalent of the following is happening:

```
use Encode qw( encode_utf8 is_utf8 );

my $bytes = is_utf8($str) ? encode_utf8($str) : $str;
```

`is_utf8` checks which of two string storage format is used by the scalar. This is an internal implementation detail you should never have to worry about, except for The Unicode Bug.

Your program works because `encode` always returns a string for which `is_utf8` returns false, and `use utf8;` always returns a string for which `is_utf8` returns true if the string contains non-ASCII characters.

If you don't `encode` as you should, you will sometimes get the wrong result. For example, if you had used `"\x{E6}2"` instead of `'æ2'`, you would have gotten a different file name even though the strings have the same length and the same characters.

```
$ dir
total 0

$ perl -wE'
   use utf8;
   $fu="æ";
   $fd="\x{E6}";
   say sprintf "%vX", $_ for $fu, $fd;
   say $fu eq $fd ? "eq" : "ne";
   system("touch", $_) for "u".$fu, "d".$fd
'
E6
E6
eq

$ dir
total 0
-rw------- 1 ikegami ikegami 0 Jul 12 12:18 uæ
-rw------- 1 ikegami ikegami 0 Jul 12 12:18 d?
```

Comment: Interesting, do you have a reference to this bug? Will it be fixed?

Comment: I doubt there's a ticket. Fixing it will probably break more code than it will fix.

Comment: I have some difficulty understanding how this bug works.., but as I understand now, the conclusion is that I should always encode filenames using for example `Encode::encode` (as I did with `$utf8_filename1`) before creating the file?

Comment: Yes, you should encode. What actually happens is that the string buffer is used without checking the UTF8 flag

Comment: More information about "The Unicode Bug" can be found in [perlunicode](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlunicode.pod#The-Unicode-Bug)