# In what encoding does readdir return a filename?

Tags: perl, ubuntu, encoding, character-encoding

Here's a Perl script that I have expected to print `found` when executed:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;
use Encode;

use constant filename => 'Bärlauch';

open (my $out, '>', filename) or die;
close $out;

opendir(my $dir, '.') or die;
while (my $filename_read = readdir($dir)) {
# $filename_read = encode('utf8', $filename_read);
  print "found\n" if $filename_read eq filename;
}
```

The script first creates a file with the name of the constant `filename`. (After running the script, I can verify the existence of the file with `ls` and the file is not created with "funny" characters.)

Then the script iterates over the files in the the current working directory and prints `found` if there is a file whose name is equal to the file just created. This should obviously be the case.

However, it doesn't (Ubuntu, bash, `LANG=en_US.UTF8`)

If I change the constant to `Barlauch`, it works as expected and prints `found`.

Uncommenting `$filename_read = encode('utf8', $filename_read);` does not change the behavior.

Is there an explanation for this and what do I do have to do in order to recognize a filename with Umlaute in it?

Comment: You should `decode` (not `encode`) `$filename_read`. See also [Could File::Find::Rule be patched to automatically handle filename character encoding/decoding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383690/could-filefindrule-be-patched-to-automatically-handle-filename-character-enc)

Comment: [Encode::Locale](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::Locale) can be informative.  Unfortunately there is wide disparity in the way File systems encode and normalize file names.  There's even a special module ([Encode::UTF8Mac](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::UTF8Mac)) dedicated to Apple's "special" implementation of Unicode in the file system.

Comment: IIRC: When using UTF-8, *nix generally uses NFC. OS X uses it's private variation on NFD (see above).  While Windows gladly creates filenames in whatever un-normalized form a user cares to throw at it.  **General Rule: Read, Normalize, then Compare**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question rephrased (as I interpret it) is:

> Why doesn't `readdir` return back the newly created filename? (Here, represented by the variable `filename` which is set to `Bärlauch`).

(Note: `filename` is a Perl constant variable, so that's why it's missing the `$` sigil in front.)

**Background:**

First note: due to the `use utf8` statement in the beginning of your program, `filename` will be upgraded to a Unicode string at compile time, since it contain non-ASCII characters. From the documentation of the [utf8](http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html) pragma:

> Enabling the utf8 pragma has the following effect: Bytes in the source
>   text that are not in the ASCII character set will be treated as being
>   part of a literal UTF-8 sequence. This includes most literals such as
>   identifier names, string constants, and constant regular expression
>   patterns.

and also, according to [perluniintro](https://metacpan.org/pod/perluniintro#Perls-Unicode-Model) section *"Perl's Unicode Model"* :

> The general principle is that Perl tries to keep its data as eight-bit
>   bytes for as long as possible, but as soon as Unicodeness cannot be
>   avoided, the data is transparently upgraded to Unicode.
>
> ...
>
> Internally, Perl currently uses whatever the native eight-bit
>   character set of the platform (for example Latin-1) is, defaulting to
>   UTF-8, to encode Unicode strings.

The non-ASCII character in `filename` is the letter `ä`. If you use ISO 8859-1 extended ASCII encoding (Latin-1), it is encoded as the byte value `0xE4`, see this [table](http://www.ascii-code.com/) at `ascii-code.com`. 
However, if you removed the `ä` character from `filename`, it would contain only ASCII characters, and therefore it would not be internally upgraded to Unicode, even if you used the `utf8` pragma.

So `filename` is now a Unicode string with the internal `UTF-8` flag set ( see [utf8](https://metacpan.org/pod/utf8) pragma for more information on the `UTF-8` flag). Note that the letter `ä` is encoded in UTF-8 as the two bytes `0xC3 0xA4`.

**Writing the file:**

When writing the file, what happens with the filename? If `filename` is a Unicode string, it will be encoded as UTF-8. However, note that it is not necessary to encode `filename` first (`encode_utf8( filename )`). See [Creating filenames with unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31371257/creating-filenames-with-unicode-characters) for more information. So the filename is written to disk as UTF-8 encoded bytes.

**Reading the filename back:**

When trying to read the filename back from disk, `readdir` does not return Unicode strings (strings with the UTF-8 flag set) even if the filename contains bytes encoded in UTF-8. It returns binary or byte strings, see [perlunitut](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlunitut) for a discussion of byte strings vs character (Unicode) strings.

Why doesn't `readdir` return Unicode strings? First, according to
[perlunicode](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlunicode.pod#When-Unicode-Does-Not-Happen) section *"When Unicode Does Not Happen"* :

> There are still many places where Unicode (in some encoding or
>   another) could be given as arguments or received as results, or both
>   in Perl, but it is not. (...)
>
> The following are such interfaces. For all of these interfaces Perl
>   currently (as of v5.16.0) simply assumes byte strings both as
>   arguments and results. (...)
>
> One reason that Perl does not attempt to resolve the role of Unicode
>   in these situations is that the answers are highly dependent on the
>   operating system and the file system(s). For example, whether
>   filenames can be in Unicode and in exactly what kind of encoding, is
>   not exactly a portable concept. (...)
>
> - chdir, chmod, chown, chroot, exec, link, lstat, mkdir, rename, rmdir,   - stat, symlink, truncate, unlink, utime, -X
> - %ENV
> - glob (aka the <*>)
> - open, opendir, sysopen
> - qx (aka the backtick operator), system
> - readdir, readlink

So `readdir` returns byte strings, since it is in general impossible to know the encoding of a file name a priori. For background information about why this is impossible, see for example:

- [filename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Encoding_interoperability) in Wikipedia, sub section "Encoding interoperability",
- [Understanding Unix file name encoding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39175/understanding-unix-file-name-encoding) on unix.stackexchange.com

**String comparison:**

Now, finally you try to compare the read filename `$filename_read` with the variable `filename`:

```
print "found\n" if $filename_read eq filename;
```

In this case the only difference between `$filename_read` and `filename`
is that `$filename_read` does not have the UTF-8 flag set (it is not what Perl internally recognize as a *"Unicode string"*).

The interesting thing now is that the result of the `eq` operator will depend upon whether the bytes in `$filename_read` is pure ASCII or not. According to the documentation of the [Encode](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode) module:

> Before the introduction of Unicode support in Perl, The `eq` operator
>   just compared the strings represented by two scalars. Beginning with
>   Perl 5.8, `eq` compares two strings with simultaneous consideration of
>   the UTF8 flag.
>
> ...
>
> When you decode, the resulting UTF8 flag is on--unless you can unambiguously represent data.

So in your case, `eq` will consider the `UTF-8` flag since `$file_name_read` does not contain pure ASCII, and as a result it will
consider the two string **not** equal. If `$filename_read` and `filename` where identical and did only contain pure ASCII bytes (and `filename` still had the UTF-8 flag set, `$filename_read` did not have the UTF-8 flag set), then `eq` would consider the two strings as equal. Se the discussion in the documentation for [Encode](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode) more information regarding the background for this behavior.

**Conclusion:**

So if you are relative confident that all your filenames are UTF-8 encoded, you could solve the issue in your question by decoding the byte string returned from `readdir` into a Unicode string (forcing the UTF-8 flag to be set):

```
$filename_read = Encode::decode_utf8( $filename_read );
```

**More details**

Note: since Unicode allows multiple representations of the same characters, there exists two forms of the `ä` (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH COMBINING DIAERESIS) in `Bärlauch`. For example,

- U+00E4 is the NFC (Normalization Form canonical Composition) form,
- U+0061.0308 is the NFD (Normalization Form canonical Decomposition) form.

On my platform (Linux), UTF-8 encoded filenames are stored using NFC form, but on Mac OS they use NFD form. See [`Encode::UTF8Mac`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::UTF8Mac) for more information. This means that if you work on a Linux machine, and for example clone a Git repository that was created by a Mac user, you can easily get NFD encoded filenames on your Linux machine. So the Linux filesystem does not care what encoding a filename is in; it just thinks of it as a sequence of bytes. Hence, I could easily write a script that created an ISO-Latin-1 encoded filename, even though my Locale is `"en_US.UTF-8"`. The current locale settings are just guidelines for applications, but if the application ignores the locale settings it is nothing that stops them from doing that.

So if you are unsure if filenames returned from `readdir` are using NFC or NFD, you should always decompose after you have decoded them:

```
use Unicode::Normalize;
print "found\n" if NFD( $filename_read ) eq NFD( filename );
```

See also [Perl Unicode Cookbook](http://www.perl.com/pub/2012/04/perl-unicode-cookbook-always-decompose-and-recompose.html) section "Always Decompose and Recompose".

Finally, to understand more about how the Locale works together with Unicode in Perl, you could have a look at:

- [perllocale](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perllocale.pod#Unicode-and-UTF-8), section "Unicode and UTF-8", and
- [Encode::Locale](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::Locale).