# Handling special characters in perl

Tags: perl

I have a perl program which moves files from one location to other location. But this program fails for the files with special characters in its name. So I have tried to replace the special characters in the file name. But I couldn't do any operation (Like rename, copy, move) on the files which have special characters in the file name. Please advise how to handle this situation.

Sample File Names which causing this issue:

```
Samplé.pdf
SampleFile®.pdf
```

Comment: check with `utf8`

Comment: See also [Reading filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/perl/4375/unicode/15288/read-filenames#t=201707100740021675739) and [In what encoding does readdir return a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37027051/2173773)