# How to check if unicode filename exists?

Tags: perl, unicode, filenames, solaris

As per [perlunicode](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#When-Unicode-Does-Not-Happen), `-e` will not work with unicode filenames, so how can I check for the existence of a unicode filename?  On a Solaris system.

Comment: "Unix" is probably not specific enough; which unix?  And what filesystem?  And what exactly do you see that says -e will not work?

Comment: Click on the link I provided and it will tell you.  It's Solaris.

Comment: I don't think you are reading it correctly; it just gives a list of places where unicode may not be portable.  That said, did you try it?  It works fine for me on linux 4.13/ext4.   Try `$fn="s\xf4l\xe2r\xees"; open $fh, ">", $fn;` and see if that creates a file `sôlârîs`.  If that doesn't work, try doing `utf8::encode($fn);` first.  Then try `-e $fn` both with and without utf8::encode.

Comment: Thanks for this. I worked out that the filenames on the Unix file system were in `cp1252` so doing this made it work `$filename = encode("cp1252", decode("utf-8", $filename))`.

Comment: See also [In what encoding does readdir return a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37027051/2173773)

Comment: @CJ7 *I worked out that the filenames on the Unix file system were in `cp1252`* - I'd be astonished if that was true. `cp1252` is a Microsoft encoding, used on legacy Windows systems. I bet what you're seeing is `ISO-8859-1` but you haven't come across any of the codepoints that differentiate it from `cp1252`.

Comment: @DaveCross "It is very common (on the Internet) to mislabel Windows-1252 text with the charset label ISO-8859-1." from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Comment: @CJ7: I don't doubt it. But just because it's a common mistake, that doesn't mean that we shouldn't try to avoid falling into it.

Answer (score 7):

On unix systems, file names are simply sequence of bytes. You have to pass to `-e` the same sequence of bytes as the actual file name. There's a good chance that it's these bytes of the UTF-8 encoding of the text you see. So if you have have Unicode Code Points ("decoded text"), try the following:

```
utf8::encode( my $fn = $decoded_text );
say -e $fn ? "exists" : "doesn't exist";
```

Don't forget to prepend the directory name if necessary.

Comment: is file name not a sequence of bytes on any other OS? Also, if file name is a sequence of bytes, is it possible that unix system has any problems with decoding them, or any program modifying file name must use the system specified encoding when changing file name? Could you please post a link to documentation clarifying this in more details?

Comment: @user1541776, In unix, any NUL-terminated sequence of bytes is a valid path. In Windows, they are encoded text, the encoding being UTF-16le or the machine's "ANSI" encoding, depending on the API used. Semantics (what characters are allowed) are associated with the decoded version, not how they are encoded.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for this. I worked out that the filenames on the Unix file system were in `cp1252` so doing this made it work `$filename = encode("cp1252", decode("utf-8", $filename))`.

Comment: Far more likely to be iso-8859-1 than a Windows-specific encoding.

Comment: @ikegami Someone copy and pasted from Windows to create the filenames.  Win 7 uses cp1252.  Also note: "It is very common (on the Internet) to mislabel Windows-1252 text with the charset label ISO-8859-1." from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Comment: Exactly. I believe you made that mistake.