# How to delete folder with unicode character filenames using Perl rmtree?

Tags: perl, unicode

I have some perl code which deletes folders using function File::Path::rmtree. This function works successfully if the folder structure contains ascii character files/folders but fails if the folder contains Unicode character files/folders..  Perl version I am using is "This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 4 (v5.12.4) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread"

I have also tried using the latest perl version., but the issue persists. Here is sample code:

```
use strict 'vars';
require File::Path;

sub Rmdir($)
{
   my ($Arena) = "D:\\tmp\\TestUnicodeRm";

   if (-d $Arena){
   print "Dir to Rmtree $Arena\n";
       File::Path::rmtree($Arena,0,0);
}

     if (-d $Arena){
        print "Failed to clean up test area $Arena.\n";
     }
}

Rmdir $0;

1;
```

If the directory 'D:\tmp\TestUnicodeRm' has file with name say 'chinese_trad_我的文件.txt' then I get error as "cannot remove directory for XXX: Directory not empty at D:\tmp\rmtree.pm line XX".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See also [In what encoding does readdir return a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37027051/2173773)

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, Most of the answer to the linked question doesn't apply because it's specific to unix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the subs provided by [Win32::Unicode::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Unicode::File) and [Win32::Unicode::Dir](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Unicode::Dir) to do what you want.

---

Windows provides two versions of each API call that accepts or returns text.

- The versions with the "A" (ANSI) suffix expect and return text encoded using the system's Active Code Page. (`"cp".Win32::GetACP()` provides an encoding name you can use with the subs provided by Encode.)

  For example, the `DeleteFileA` system call is used to delete a file, and it expects a path encoded using the system's Active Code Page.
- The versions with the "W" (Wide) suffix expect and return text encoded using UTF-16le.

  For example, the `DeleteFileW` system call is used to delete a file, and it expects a path encoded using UTF-16le.

Perl uses the "A" version of all system calls. The "W" version is required here.

The modules mentioned above provide access to the "W" version of calls you need.

Comment: Accepted as answer, as this looks to be most accurate for my requirement. I however failed to build the module on my machine, so could not actually test it. I will try it out again once I have some free time.

Answer (score 2):

Filenames are always bytes. Unfortunately there is no indication or requirement for unicode characters in filenames to be represented in a certain encoding, and every OS has different conventions. In most Unix-like systems the filenames are encoded to UTF-8 and interacted with as bytes. However in Windows the filenames are stored as UTF-16, but interacted with as decoded characters. It sounds like a bug in File::Path that it doesn't properly deal with these filenames as it finds them - as you are not providing the filenames, it can't be a bug in your code.

I would first suggest making sure your File::Path is the latest version (2.16). If this doesn't work, all I can suggest is to report a bug, and either manually recursively use opendir and readdir to remove files and subdirectories, or shell out to [rd /s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rd).

```
my $rc = system 'rd', '/s', $dir; # check for errors as in system() docs
```

Comment: Re "*Filenames are always bytes*", Not in Windows. They are strings of 16-bit values there. /// Re "*there is no indication or requirement for unicode characters in filenames to be represented in a certain encoding*", In Windows, file names are encoded using UTF-16le, and must therefore be encodable using that encoding.  /// Re "*but interacted with as decoded characters*", Quite the opposite. Perl uses calls that expect/return the file name encoded using the system's ACP. /// Re "*It sounds like a bug in File::Path*, It's a known bug/limit of Perl funcs that's merely inherited by File::Path.

Comment: @Grinnz Thanks for your comment. I tried with File::Path version 2.15 and it was still failing.  We are using  'rd'/'rmdir' as the alternative solution, but we wanted to avoid it and instead use some lib/module implementation.