# In Perl how to move folder in which folder name has junk letters?

Tags: regex, perl, utf-8

How to move the folder, in which folder name containing junk characters. (ex:Theoretical Analysis_Ferda Ã–zdemir SÃ¶nmez). Here there are some letters Ã & ¶). Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What OS? What encoding do you use on the file system? Does your Perl script use [utf8](http://p3rl.org/utf8)?

Comment: Yes i used utf8, OS is windows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1721807/1030675 might help you.

Comment: Still I didn't get an output for this question. Anybody please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Win32::Unicode::Dir](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Unicode::Dir). For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Win32::Unicode::Console;
use Win32::Unicode::Dir ();

my $dir = 'SÃ¶nmez';
my $dest = 'temp';
Win32::Unicode::Dir::mkpathW($dest) or dieW "Could not create directory '$dest': $!";
Win32::Unicode::Dir::mvtreeW( "${dir}/", $dest) or dieW  "Cannot move '$dir' to '$dest': $!";
Win32::Unicode::Dir::rmdirW( $dir) or dieW "Cannot delete source directory name '$dir': $!";
```

See also [How to delete folder with unicode character filenames using Perl rmtree?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55616658/2173773)